# Force defined php.ini log file

Tags: php, apache, lamp

php.ini:

```
error_log = /var/log/php.log
```

Running on shell:

```
php@> error_log("test"); 
// WRITES TO /var/log/php.log
```

Running on apache index.php:

```
error_log("test"); 
// WRITES to apache/error_log
```

Apache 2.4.6 / Php 5.4.16

- I already checked for alternative php.ini files
- What i need is the apache directive that controls it, already looked in the man page.
- Already checked permissions and file ownership

Comment: They are using different php.ini files. Probably one in `/etc/php5/cli` and the other one in `/etc/php5/apache`

Comment: no alternative php.ini files, already checked.

Comment: So the error_log inside the phpinfo(); page shows the same as output of `php -i | grep error_log` command?

Comment: i had phpinfo disabled but it just enabled to check and it's the same. /var/log/httpd/php.log (i moved to httpd log folder to check if it was a permission issue from apache but nothing changed.);

Comment: Note also that `php.ini` values can be overridden in the Apache config.

Answer (score 0):

You may set this path directly from the PHP code. For example:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/logs/php-error.log");
```

Comment: Yes, i saw this in another thread. I want to know what is going on, i had it working with just error_log() in another server.

Comment: To find a path to real php.ini file you can use phpinfo() function

Answer (score 0):

My new vps have SELinux enabled so i had to add this attr to the file

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_log_t php.log
```